# Twilio API is throwing ERROR - Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class

Tags: java, apache-axis, twilio

I am using Twilio API to shoot international SMS with JAVA AXIS2 web services. When implemented in a standalone application Twilio API is successful in sending SMS but when plug in to Web service throws the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class

I am using twilio-java-sdk-4.4.5 jar

Sample Code:

```
    final TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", "+############")); 
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+############")); 
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", "Hi, How are you doing today?!")); 
MessageFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getMessageFactory(); 
         Message message = messageFactory.create(params);
```

StackTrace :

```
ERROR - Cannot inherit from final class
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
....
....
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2928)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.createHttpParams(DefaultHttpClient.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getParams(AbstractHttpClient.java:448)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioClient.<init>(TwilioClient.java:143)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.<init>(TwilioRestClient.java:19)
    at com.abc.util.SendSMS.sendSmsviaTwilio(SendSMS.java:205)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760000/java-applet-cannot-inherit-from-final-class read the answer for this question. I think this is also a similar scenario. There should be two versions of dependencies and one has a final class and other version has a non final class.

Comment: Thats Correct that it has version conflict but how do i resolve it.

Comment: Have you identified which packages are having version conflicts ?

Comment: Yeah I got it, it was http-client.jar that was causing the conflict. Thanks !!

Comment: Cool. I have added my comment as an answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

[Java Applet - Cannot inherit from final class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760000/java-applet-cannot-inherit-from-final-class) Read the answer for this question. I think this is also a similar scenario. There should be two versions of dependencies and one has a final class and other version has a non final class.